# ¿Por qué el scanner solo me lee 3 datos de 6?

Tags: java

**EJERCICIO QUE ME PIDEN HACER**

En este problema, la tarea consiste en leer un código de un producto 1, el número de unidades del producto 1, el precio de una unidad de producto 1, el código de un producto 2, el número de unidades del producto 2 y el precio de una unidad de producto 2. Después de esto, calcular y mostrar la cantidad a pagar.

Mi Código

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
public class Main{
    public static void main(String ars[]){
        int code1, unid1, code2, unid2;
        float price1, price2, total;
        
        Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("primer dato");
        code1 = key.nextInt();
        System.out.println("segundo dato");
        unid1 = key.nextInt();
        System.out.println("tercero dato");
        price1 = key.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("cuarto dato");
        code2 = key.nextInt();
        System.out.println("cinco dato");
        unid2 = key.nextInt();
        System.out.println("seis dato");
        price2 = key.nextFloat();

        total = (unid1*price1)+ (unid2*price2);

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
        System.out.println("VALOR A PAGAR: R$ "+df.format(total));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yo probé tu código con: `2, 3, 3.12, 5, 8, 5.31`  y la salida fue `VALOR A PAGAR: R$ 51.84`. Supongo que es problema de tus datos, entonces

Comment: Yo probé para uni1=1, price1=2,uni2=3,price2=4 y la salida fue ``R$ 14.00``, entonces al menos el valor total está bien.

Comment: @joshin  cuando ejecuto mi codigo al ingresar el tercer dato me aparece esto despues de ingresarlo:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextFloat(Unknown Source)
        at main.main(main.java:14)

Comment: Eso es porque tu IDE está configurado para que recibas los decimales con ``,`` y seguramente estas ingresando los decimales con ``.``

Comment: Listo, muchas gracias :D